# Find delimiter in txt to convert to csv using Python

Tags: python, csv

I have to convert some txt files to csv
(and make some operation during the conversion).

I use csv.Sniffer() class to detect wich delimiter is used in the txt

This code

```
with open(filename_input, 'r') as f1, open(filename_output, 'wb') as f2:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f1.read(1024)) #### detect delimiters  
    f1.seek(0)
    r=csv.reader(f1, delimiter=dialect )
    writer = csv.writer(f2,delimiter=';')
```

return: Error: Could not determine delimiter

This work

```
with open(filename_input, 'r') as f1, open(filename_output, 'wb') as f2:
    #dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f1.read(1024)) #### detect delimiters  
    #f1.seek(0)
    r=csv.reader(f1, delimiter='\t' )
    writer = csv.writer(f2,delimiter=';')
```

or

```
with open(filename_input, 'r') as f1, open(filename_output, 'wb') as f2:
    #dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f1.read(1024)) #### detect delimiters  
    #f1.seek(0)
    r=csv.reader(f1, dialect="excel-tab")
    writer = csv.writer(f2,delimiter=';')
```

this is a txt row example (10 records delimited by Tab)

```
166 14908941    sa_s    NOVA i  7.05    DEa 7.17    Ncava - Deo mo  7161    4,97
```

why  csv.Sniffer() class doesn't work?

The bug was read only 1024 byte to parse the entire txt(maybe this is not enough to detect the delimiter).
Now this code works without no other edit:

```
with open(filename_input, 'r') as f1, open(filename_output, 'wb') as f2:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f1.read()) #### error with dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f1.read(1024))  
    f1.seek(0)
    r=csv.reader(f1, delimiter=dialect )
    writer = csv.writer(f2,delimiter=';')
```

Comment: And what is `dialect ` as returned by `csv.excel_tab().sniff(f1.read(1024))`? And if your code works then I don't really understand the problem, as much as I admire curiosity.

Comment: Sorry i make an error it was `csv.Sniffer().sniff(f1.read(1024))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `dialect.delimiter` instead of just `dialect` because what is returned is of type class Dialect and you need its [attribute](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.delimiter) `Dialect.delimiter`

```
rows=csv.reader(f1, delimiter=dialect.delimiter)
```

Modified code will be as below

```
import csv

filename_input = 'filein.txt'
filename_output = 'fileout.csv'
with open(filename_input, 'r') as f1, open(filename_output, 'wb') as f2:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f1.read(1024), "\t") #### detect delimiters
    f1.seek(0)
    print(dialect.delimiter)
    rows=csv.reader(f1, delimiter=dialect.delimiter)
    writer = csv.writer(f2,delimiter=';')
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Output:

> C:\pyp>python.exe txttocsv.py
>    ,
>    C:\pyp>

Also note that [from doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer.sniff):

> sniff(sample, delimiters=None)
>
> Analyze the given sample and return a Dialect subclass reflecting
>   the parameters found. If the optional delimiters parameter is given,
>   it is interpreted as a string containing possible valid delimiter
>   characters.

Hence if the delimiter that you want to find in your text file is something like `#` instead of `,` or `;` then you should mention that in `sniff` function as second parameter like this:

```
dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f1.read(1024), '#')
```

Update: For reading whole file you will need

```
dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f1.read())
```

Comment: `dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f1.read(1024))` return error first of print and `dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f1.read(1024),'\t')` return error too

Comment: Which version of python are you using? For python3, you need print statement as `print(dialect.delimiter)`

Comment: @user2418290 You have to post the error. Otherwise its not clear what you mean?

Comment: python 2.7. The error is the same: "Could not determine delimiter"

Comment: Can I send all the txt file? by email?

Comment: in all file `print dialect.delimiter` return l

Comment: @user2418290 thats because it looks for `,` or `;` and when it doesnt find it takes `l` as delimiter

Comment: Sorry in my original post I write edited data because it is sensitive.This is an original row `201 8509340 f5i ROZZANO Via_Milano 6.03 ROZZANO Via_Maggi 6.31 Rozzano (Milano) - Rozzano (Maggi)                                               5522 8,17`

Comment: Is it seperated by tab or space

Comment: @user2418290 Ok. It is working for me. You need to put \t in double quotes as argument `"\t"` to sniff

Comment: @userDA14 it works for that row, for the entire file it returns the same error   `if not delimiter:         raise Error, "Could not determine delimiter"`

Comment: @franco_b I have copied the same row 4 times and it is working fine.

Comment: @userDA14 I have founded the bug. I have to use  `dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f1.read())` instead of   `dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f1.read(1024))` . Maybe it needs to read all the file to found the delimiter. Now works even without `"\t"` as argument

Answer (score 0):

The code works but in CSV that is generated each record is skipping one line.

The code i used :-

```
import csv

filename_input = r'filepath.txt'
filename_output = r'filepath.csv'
with open(filename_input, 'r') as tmp, open(filename_output, 'w') as tmp2:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(tmp.read(1024), ";") #### detect delimiters
    tmp.seek(0)
    print(dialect.delimiter)
    rows=csv.reader(tmp, delimiter=dialect.delimiter)
    writer = csv.writer(tmp2,delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Input:-

[image: Input]

Output:-

[image]