# Delimiter with tab in text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

Want to find the delimiter in the text file.

The text looks:

```
ID;    Name
1;     John Mak
2;     David H 
4;     Herry
```

The file consists of tabs with the delimiter.

I tried with following: [by referring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407993/find-delimiter-in-txt-to-convert-to-csv-using-python)

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f1:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f1.read(1024), "\t")
    print 'Delimiter:', dialect.delimiter
```

The result shows: `Delimiter:`

Expected result: `Delimiter: ;`

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @DataScienceStep, `Delimiter: ;`

Comment: Can't you just remove the `"\t"` argument and it should discover the delimiter as `;`, by passing in `\t` you are suggesting to the sniffer that the delimiter is a tab. Tested with the above snippet and it returns a dialect with `delimiter=';'`

Comment: @MAK so if you just want to find ; and print it why you don't use print(s[s.find(';')]) #suppose s is your text string

Comment: @DataScienceStep, Delimiter is not fixed. That's why I said, Want to find the delimiter in the text file

Comment: @MAK maybe I don't get your point but find() will return the position of the first occurring ;  in the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sniff` can conclude with only one single character as the delimiter. Since your CSV file contains two characters as the delimiter, `sniff` will simply pick one of them. But since you also pass in the optional second argument to `sniff`, it will only pick what's contained in that value as a possible delimiter, which in your case, is `'\t'` (which is not visible from your `print` output).

From [`sniff`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer.sniff):

> If the optional *delimiters* parameter is given, it is interpreted as a
>   string containing possible valid delimiter characters.

Comment: How can I get only `;` by escaping tab without mentioning option to `sniff`? Because delimiter is not fixed in my case.

Comment: @MAK The real problem is that no CSV should have a two-character long delimiter, which is the case in the sample text in your question. In other words, your sample text is not actually a valid CSV. If it had only either `;` or a tab as the delimiter (but not both), then you can pass `';\t'` as the second argument to `sniff` to let it pick, or you can even not pass a second argument to let it make its own best guess.

Answer (score 1):

Sniffing is not guaranteed to work.

Here is one approach that will work with any kind of delimiter.

You start with what you assume is the most common delimiter `;` if that fails, then you try others until you manage to parse the row.

```
import csv

with open('sample.csv') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
  for row in reader:
    try:
      a,b = row
    except ValueError:
      try:
         a,b = row[0].split(None, 1)
      except ValueError:
        a,b = row[0].split('\t', 1)
    print('{} - {}'.format(a.strip(), b.strip()))
```

You can play around with this at [this replt.it link](https://repl.it/repls/KindQuizzicalMultiprocessing), play with the `sample.csv` file if you want to try out different delimiters.

You can combine sniffing with this to catch any odd delimiters that are not known to you.